# UML sequence diagram break operator

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Does the break happen after doing the `save()` message in below sequence diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Definition from UML2.5

> **Break**
>
> The interactionOperator break designates that the CombinedFragment represents a breaking scenario in the sense that the operand is a scenario that is performed instead of the remainder of the enclosing InteractionFragment. A break operator with a guard is chosen when the guard is true and the rest of the enclosing Interaction Fragment is ignored. When the guard of the break operand is false, the break operand is ignored and the rest of the enclosing InteractionFragment is chosen. The choice between a break operand without a guard and the rest of the enclosing InteractionFragment is done non-deterministically.
>
> A CombinedFragment with interactionOperator break should cover all Lifelines of the enclosing InteractionFragment.